# How to create a multiline list?

Tags: java, netbeans, java-me, lwuit

How to create a multiline list in J2ME like this: [multiline list](http://today.java.net/images/2008/08/list.png)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems the demo of LWUIT's List component have a look at [here](http://lwuit.blogspot.com/2008/07/lwuit-list-renderer-by-chen-fishbein.html) & [here](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/38461/1954)

Comment: Thank you.Can you give me a simple example? I am beginner.

Comment: [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javame/lwuit_intro/) is the demo